# Failed to connet to a VPN server via OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

The server is located in Germany and I am in Africa.
When I was in Germany I can connect to the server (same newtork with the server or via other connection). But in other country I can not connect, after 30 second will fail. I though that's the Config was wrong, but it looks that Timeout issue.
I am usign Windows 10 with OpenVPN GUI, and I have not access to the Server Config side.
Can it be a router issue or what?

Answer (score 0):

I added mssfix 1200, it solves my problem